# How was Edmure Tully convinced by Jaime Lannister?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

I've watched this scene 3-4 times but I still couldn't understand how Edmure was convinced by the King-slayer. Jaime mentions about Catelyn, Cercei & her love for their children and they can go to any end to protect them.

He then mentions about Edmure & his new born son.

Did Edmure Tully really feared for his child and gave up River-run or he was sick of being a prisoner or did he give the castle so that he can get out of captive & then strike on the Frey's with a plan whenever he is ready again?

Comment: I think it's a good point to think that Edmure might be plotting his revenge while he seemingly surrenders. My only problem with this idea is that we've seen Edmure be a bit of a fool and he tends to make unsound tactical decisions. (Can't shoot a flaming arrow correctly, attacking the wrong targets)

Comment: yeah, but that's before he was taken as a prisoner. He used to be a Lord & was raised without any pain or struggle. Now, he has nothing else left except for the name. I think he'll work harder now.

Comment: Cross-Site dupes - [Why did Edmure do what he did in S06E08](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/131776/54887) & [Why did Edmure agree to Jaime's demands?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133769/54887)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, Edmure surrendered because of threats to his family and because it looked like a no-win situation.**

**Family** plays a huge part in the Game of Thrones universe.

It's important in ours as well, of course, but for them it's more than just loving and protecting your family. It's about duty to your family; honour, respect, legacy, loyalty.

If you don't show proper love, care and loyalty to your own family, why should your other allied houses be loyal, respectful and care for you?

Also the leader of a house without an heir won't be a powerful house for very long.

But most importantly I think it came down to **a father having his son threatened**. Despite not knowing the child, Edmure no doubt feels a great deal of attachment and sense of protection for his son.

We've seen men go to great lengths to protect sons:

- Eddard Stark protects newborn Jon Snow to great lengths, despite Jon being a bastard. Even though in Season 6 we learn that:

> Jon Snow is the son of Eddard's **sister Lyanna**. Despite not being his son, Eddard is duty and honour-bound to protect this child at all costs.

- Tywin Lannister is disgusted at his newborn son, Tyrion for "being a monster" and "killing" Tywin's wife. Despite this, Tywin explains that he did not throw Tyrion into a river because **Tyrion is Tywin's son** and **he is a Lannister** (family).

Jaime threatens that he will catapult Edmure's son over the walls of the castle and then lay siege to it. Knowing that the Lannisters are rich and powerful (at least to Edmure's knowledge), and with the Throne at their side, Edmure sees all of this as a losing situation.

He reasons that the best bet for his survival, his son's survival, his family's legacy and the lives of his people (all of House Tully), is to surrender and live so that he can try to be powerful once again some day.

That's my understanding anyway.

Comment: The words of House Tully: "Family, Duty, Honor." Family comes first.

Comment: @nasukkin Oh wow, nice pickup.

Comment: There's even a scene in Season 1 (Episide 5) where Bran and Maester Luwin go through an exchange - "Bran Stark: Family, Duty, Honor. Is that the right order?
Maester Luwin: You know it is. 
Bran Stark: Family comes first. " This relates to Bran's feeling that Catelyn Stark née Tully can't be there for her family when she has left Winterfell, but equally drives the point home for Edmure Tully.

Comment: To support the importance of being loyal to your family (even if only for your public image): look at how much Tywin hated Tyrion; yet still _publically_ treated him no different from Jaime. Tywin's hate only came out in private conversations, and Tyrion often had to push Tywin to explain his actions before it was even mentioned (though his actions did already showcase his disdain by themselves)

Comment: Eddard also public "confessed" to treason and proclaimed Jeoffrey as authentically a Baratheon just to protect his daughters, just before being double-crossed and killed.  Think about how important Ned's honor was to him. To publicly besmirch his name, reputation and family like that was a pretty big deal, so family must have been an even bigger deal.

Comment: Plus we know that Edmure is considered a bit soft and weak, especially compared to the Blackfish, so Jamie probably calculated that he could be broken in such a manner.